# How to group_by(x) and summarise by counting distinct(y) for each x level?

Tags: r, dplyr, summarization

I have the following situation:

| V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | A1 |
| A | A1 |
| A | A1 |
| A | A2 |
| A | A2 |
| A | A3 |
| B | B1 |
| B | B2 |
| B | B2 |

and i need to group by V1, and summarise counting how many distinct groups each V1 level has in V2. Something like this:

| V1 | n |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 2 |

How can i use dplyr funcitons to solve that?

Thanks!!

Comment: `df |> group_by(V1) |> summarise(n = n_distinct(V2)) |> ungroup()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rle` after grouping by 'V1'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(V1) %>%
   summarise(n = length(rle(V2)$values), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  V1        n
  <chr> <int>
1 A         3
2 B         2
```

---

Or with `rleid` and `n_distinct`

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(V1) %>% 
  summarise(n = n_distinct(rleid(V2)))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  V1        n
  <chr> <int>
1 A         3
2 B         2
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", 
"B"), V2 = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A1", "B1", "B2", 
"B2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```